# Excel Date Error : 1-0 (Month and Day) for blank dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am getting 1-0 (Month and Day) for blank dates in Excel. How do i solve this this? I used

`=CONCATENATE(MONTH([@[Date]]),"-",DAY([@[Date]]))`

```
Date          Month Month-Day
12/1/2017 0:01  12  12-1
12/1/2017 0:01  12  12-1
12/1/2017 0:07  12  12-1
12/1/2017 0:07  12  12-1
                1   1-0
                1   1-0
12/1/2017 0:10  12  12-1
12/1/2017 1:08  12  12-1
12/1/2017 1:16  12  12-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=IF([@date], CONCATENATE(MONTH([@date]),"-",DAY([@date])), TEXT(,))
```